# Proxy CORS requests with grunt to localhost

Tags: javascript, proxy, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect, grunt-connect-proxy

My app (`http://localhost:8099`) is doing some CORS requests to `https://api.parse.com/` that I want to proxy to my local api `http://localhost:8077` for testing purposes. Can this be achived with `grunt-connect-proxy`?

Here's my config of grunt-connect-proxy that does not work like I expect.

```
connect: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          port: 8099,
          hostname: 'localhost',
          base: 'build/',
          livereload: false,
          keepalive: true,
          middleware: function (connect, options) {
            var proxy = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest;
            return [
              // Include the proxy first
              proxy,
              // Serve static files.
              connect.static('build/')
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      proxies: [
      {
        context: ['api/'], //same domain api requests, proxy works fine!
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8077
      },
      {
        context: ['api.parse.com/'], //cors, proxy is not working
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8077,
        changeOrigin: true
      }]

    }

→ grunt serve
Proxy created for: api/ to localhost:8077
Proxy created for: api.parse.com/ to localhost:8077
```

So, basically proxying is works for `api/` requests (same domain), but is completely ignored for cors requests to `api.parse.com/`. Ideas?

Comment: Did u got the solution? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: @prudviraju in the end i turned down the idea of proxying, i simply change the api endpoint in the runtime according to the NODE_ENV

Comment: can you share more information please

Comment: @prudviraju sure, the solution was as simple as this: `apiEndpoint = window.location.host === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost:8077' : 'https://api.parse.com`.

Answer (score 1):

When you will make request to `api.parse.com`, browser will connect to actual parse.com server. grunt-connect-proxy comes into picture only when requests are made to application server which is localhost:8099 in your case.

Everything else other localhost:8099 is remote/cross domain for your application (even localhost:8077) and you can use grunt-connect-proxy to connect to these servers in the server side, while on client side you will still make requests to your own server.

Which server to connect to when proxying is configured using the context.

```
proxies: [
      {
        context: ['api/'],
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8077
      },
      {
        context: ['parse/'], 
        host: 'api.parse.com'
      }]
```

So, considering above configurations

`localhost:8099/api` --> Will got to `localhost:8077`

and

`localhost:8099/parse` --> will go to `api.parse.com`

Comment: Doesn't `options.host` mean the host to proxy **to**?